# DataCamp crossjoin task not accepted. Eventhough i use solution

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

How do I solve that issue?

**Errormessage**:
Incorrect Submission
Check the highlighted code. Could not find the second entry in the fields.

```
-- Select first and last names
SELECT e.FirstName || ' ' || e.LastName AS "Employee",
       c.FirstName || ' ' || c.LastName AS "Customer",
       sum(i) AS "Total"
-- Join Employee with Customer
FROM Employee e CROSS JOIN Customer c 
-- Join with Invoice
CROSS JOIN Invoice i on c.customerid = i.customerid
-- Filter for support agents only
WHERE e.Title = 'Sales Support Agent' 
GROUP BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, c.FirstName, c.LastName
```

Comment: write your question as a text instead of image

Comment: i is a table i think the column is total, that needs to be summed up

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
-- Select first and last names
SELECT e.FirstName || ' ' || e.LastName AS "Employee",
       c.FirstName || ' ' || c.LastName AS "Customer",
       sum(i.total) AS "Total"
-- Join Employee with Customer
FROM Employee e CROSS JOIN Customer c 
-- Join with Invoice
     Inner join Invoice i ON c.customerid = i.customerid
-- Filter for support agents only
WHERE e.Title = 'Sales Support Agent'
GROUP BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, c.FirstName, c.LastName
```